# Putting instantiation on index.php works, on header.php it doesn't

Tags: php

I got a login script in the header and it instantiates a new Session where it will set a session cookie. For some reason the script stops working at the instantiation (`$session->login($found_user`). $found_user returns the User object with all the data (including the id).

The session class method of login:

```
public function login($user) {
   if($user) {
      $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
      $this->_logged_in = true;
   }
}
```

If I copy my header.php code into my index.php it does work.

My initializing of the session class which happens before calling the header at the index.php:

`defined('LIB_PATH') ? null : define('LIB_PATH', SITE_ROOT.DS.'includes');`

```
require_once(LIB_PATH.DS.'class.Session.php');
```

Is there are path problem?

My static method to find the user does work.. So why does one method work and the other one doesn't.

The code where the user object is found:

```
$found_user = User::authenticate($email, $password);
    if($found_user) {
       $session->login($found_user);
       redirect_to("index.php");
    }
```

$found_user returns the User object and when I echo $found_user->id, I'm getting the id.

**Getting the following error:** 
Notice: Undefined variable: session in */header.php on line 41 Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object in */header.php on line 41

**Edit with more code
My session class:**

```
class Session {

    // Attributes
    private $_logged_in = false;
    public  $user_id;

    // Constructor
    function __construct() {
        session_set_cookie_params(24*60*60);
        session_start();
        $this->check_message();
        $this->check_login();
    }

    // Validation
    public function is_logged_in() {
        return $this->_logged_in;
    }

    private function check_login() {
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
            $this->_logged_in = true;
        } else {
            unset($this->user_id);
            $this->_logged_in = false;
        }
    }

    // Login - Logout
    public function login($user) {
        if($user) {
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $this->_logged_in = true;
        }
    }

    public function logout() { ...
    } 
}

$session = new Session();
```

The code where the user is found and passed into the login method:

```
$found_user = User::authenticate($email, $password);
if($found_user) {
   $session->login($found_user);
   redirect_to("index.php");
}
```

$found_user returns the User object and `$found_user->id` gives the id of the `$found_user`:

User Object ( [id] => 3 ) and more data from that row.

**SOLUTION:**
Found the problem. Had to put global $session; before calling the class method.

Comment: Please show us the code where $user is defined.

Comment: Getting the following error: Notice: Undefined variable: session in ***/header.php on line 41 Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object in ***/header.php on line 41

Comment: if I add '$session = new Session();' above the $session->login(), it works.. But in my session class I already have $session = new Session(); at the end of the class.

Comment: You are referencing code which you did not post here. So it's impossible to advice you in this question.

Comment: Which code would you like me to post? I assume the problem lies in the difference of calling a static method and an instance method. Whereas the instance method is undefined and the static method is defined. The classes are loaded in index.php.

Comment: If in your session class you are instantiating a session variable called $session. This variable is not available in another class. You have to specifically make that external class variable accessible or call upon it. But it's difficult to point out, unless we see all code and not just a fraction.

Comment: Updated with some more code, hope it's clear now :)

Comment: what's the result of $found_user?

Comment: 'User Object ( [id] => 3 )' and more data from that row.

Comment: Found the problem. Had to put global $session; before calling the class method.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. Had to put global $session; before calling the class method.